# How to cite an exhibition catalogue with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm trying to cite an exhibtion catalogue, but I cannot find the right entry type for the bib file. I'm using Texmaker 3.5.2 to write the source code, Tex Live 2012 is my distribution and the command chain to include the bibliography is latex->bibtex8->latex.

I want to convert a document written in Libreoffice to Latex. In Libreoffice the entry for the exhibition catalogue looks like this:

Berliner Kulturveranstaltungs-GmbH (Hrsg.): *İskorpit. Aktuelle Kunst aus Istanbul*, Ausst. Kat. Berlin, Haus der Kulturen der Welt, 15.10.-15.11.1998, Berlin 1998.

Using

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
@misc{Berliner:Iskorpit,
    title = {\.{I}skorpit. Aktuelle Kunst aus Istanbul},
    author = {Berliner Kulturveranstaltungs-GmbH (Hrsg.)},
    howpublished = {Ausst. Kat. Berlin, Haus der Kulturen der Welt, 15.10.-15.11.1998, Berlin 1998},
}
```

Results in

[1] Berliner Kulturveranstaltungs-GmbH (Hrsg.) ˙ *Iskorpit. Aktuelle Kunst aus Istanbul*.
Ausst. Kat. Berlin, Haus der Kulturen der Welt, 15.10.-15.11.1998, Berlin 1998.

which is almost what I'm looking for. Except for the missing colon before the title, and the period after the title, which has to be substituted by a comma.

I don't know if @misc is the appropriate entry type. Is there another one I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following configuration:

- Instead of `author` I would use `editor`. The string `Hrsg` will be selected automatically based on the current language loaded by `babel` or `polyglossia`.
- With the following definition you will get parens around the string `Hrsg.`.

  ```
  \DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
  ```
- The next defintions puts a colon instead of a dot between the author/editor part and the title.

  ```
  \renewcommand\labelnamepunct{\addcolon\space}
  ```

---

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Berliner:Iskorpit,
    title = {\.{I}skorpit. Aktuelle Kunst aus Istanbul},

    editor = "{Berliner Kulturveranstaltungs-GmbH}",
    howpublished = {Ausst. Kat. Berlin, Haus der Kulturen der Welt, 15.10.-15.11.1998, Berlin 1998},
}
\end{filecontents}
%\listfiles
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewcommand\labelnamepunct{\addcolon\space}
\begin{document}
Text \cite{Berliner:Iskorpit}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

Removing the comma before the editor string:

```
\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     %\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is almost exactly what I was looking for. The last small glitch is that now there is a comme before "(Hrsg.)". Would you be able to remove that? Could you point out a reference, where the process of customizing such small adjustments to the bibliography is described?

Comment: @BdN3504: I added a solution. Most of the thinks are explained in the documentation. For me the file `biblatex.def` is also part of the documentation. If you are from Germany, this can help you http://texwelt.de/blog/hilfe-zu-biblatex/ (I wrote this some weeks ago)