# Author-year citation how to cite a Catalog?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have a question about `\citep` command. In my work I use a author-name citation but I have to cite a catalogue of parts. When I use a `@misc` entry with a name and note field than I have error - not compatible with citation author-name. How can I do correctly the citation of catalogue?

Comment: Hello pawelch, maybe this link can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160590/how-to-cite-an-exhibition-catalogue-with-bibtex

Comment: Or [this](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) might help you.